# Traer datos de una tabla dependiendo del select en la misma pagina

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Antonio Galicia me paso el archivo JS, todavía no he podido hacer funcionar .
La idea es que cuando uno seleccione un motivo de viaje me muestre todos los pasajeros que tiene el mismo motivo de viaje.

Con ese select traigo desde la base de datos todos los motivos de viaje.

```
include_once("conexion.php");
$base = "SELECT * FROM viajes ORDER BY id_viaje ASC";
$nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $base);
$id_viaje = (!empty ($_GET['id_viaje']) ) ? $_GET['id_viaje'] : NULL; 

//SELECT CON LOS MOTIVOS DEL VIAJE
echo "<label for='viaje' class='form-label'><strong>ELIJA EL VIAJE</strong></label>";
echo "<select class='form-select' name='id_viaje' id='viaje' required>";
echo "<option value='' disabled selected hidden></option>";
while($crow = mysqli_fetch_array($nquery)){
    $fechaida = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($crow['fechaida']));
    echo "<option value='".$crow['id_viaje']."' data-fecha='".$fechaida."'>".$crow['motivo']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Aca les dejo el JS que me paso Antonio Galicia.

```
//FUNCION QUE DETECTA LA CARGA COMPLETA DEL DOM
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //OBTENEMOS ELEMENTO SELECT DE VIAJES MEDIANTE SU ID
  var select_viajes = document.getElementById('viajes');
  //FUNCION QUE DETECTA SI HAY CAMBIO DE OPCION DEL SELECT
  select_viajes.addEventListener('change', function() {
    //OBTENEMOS EL ELEMNTO EN EL QUE VAMOS A PINTAR LA RESPUESTA DE PHP
    var divtabla = document.getElementById('dataViajes');
    //OBTENEMOS EL VALUE DE LA OPCION SELECCIONADA, THIS HACE REFERENCIA SOBRE EL LEMENTO QUE EJECUTA EL EVENTO
    var id_viaje = this.value;
    //PETICION QUE ENVIA EL ID DEL VIAJE POR METODO POST
    //CON AJAX EVITAMOS LA RECARGA DE LA PAGINA, LO HACE EN LA MISMA
    $.ajax({
      //RUTA DE PHP
      url: 'ruta.php',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'text',
      //DATOS A ENVIAR
      data: {
        id: id_viaje,
      },
      //SI LA PETICION SE RESUELVE SATISFACTORIAMENTE PINTAMOS LA DATA EN ESTE ELEMENTO
      success: function(response) {
       divtabla.innerHTML = response;
      },
      //SI FALLA, MUSTRA UN ALERT CON MENSAJE DE ERROR
      error: function() {
        alert('NO SE PUDO COMPLETAR LA PETICION');
      }
    });
  })
})
```

y ese seria el archivo ruta.php

```
    include_once("conexion.php");
    
    $motivo = isset($_POST['motivo']) ? $_POST['motivo'] : NULL;
    $id_viaje = isset($_POST['id_viaje']) ? $_POST['id_viaje'] : NULL;
    //LISTADO PERSONAL           
    $consulta = "SELECT pasajeros.id, pasajeros.apellido, pasajeros.nombre, pasajeros.dni, pasajeros.vencedni, pasajeros.fechan, pasajeros.nacion, pasajeros.equipaje, pasajeros.idavuelta, pasajeros.spml, pasajeros.hotel, pasajeros.obs, viajes.motivo, viajes.fechaida, viajes.transporte FROM pasajeros LEFT JOIN viajes ON pasajeros.viaje_id = viajes.id_viaje WHERE viajes.id_viaje='$id_viaje'";    
    $respuesta = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);
    $id_viaje = (!empty ($_GET['id_viaje']) ) ? $_GET['id_viaje'] : NULL; 
        
        
?>

<table width="100%" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <!--<th>ID</th>-->
    <th width="25%">VIAJE A</th>
    <th width="13%">FECHA</th>
    <th width="17%">APELLIDO</th>
    <th width="21%">NOMBRE</th>
    <th width="15%">TRASNPORTE</th>
    <!--<th width="8%" class="text-center">EDITAR</th>-->
    <th width="9%" class="text-center">ELIMINAR</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
        
    <?php
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta)){
    //Cambio Formateo de fecha
    $fechaida = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($fila['fechaida']));
    ?>
        
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <!--<td><?php //echo $crow['id_viaje']; ?></td>-->
    <td><?php echo $fila['motivo']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fechaida; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila['apellido']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila['transporte']; ?></td>
    <!--EDITAR PERSONAL-->
    <!--<td class='text-center'><a href='editar-viaje.php?id_viaje=<?php //echo $crow['id_viaje'];?> ' title="Editar Viaje"><button type='button' class='fas fa-1x fa-edit border-0' style='color:#ff6318;'></button></a></td>-->
    <!--ELIMINAR PERSONAL-->
    <td class="text-center">
    <a onclick="eliminarViaje('<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>')" title="Eliminar Pasajero">
    <button type="button" class="fas fa-1x fa-trash-alt border-0" style="color: red;"></button></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php
        }       
    ?>
    </table>
```

Con eso no me funciona y me sale error en la consola:
home.php:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at home.php:27:17

No tengo experiencia en Ajax, no se donde puede estar el error.
No se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: En que archivo tenes tu codigo de AJAX que te paso esta persona? El error dice algo como que metiste codigo de JS en un archivo PHP, en ``home.php`` para ser preciso

Comment: Hola gracias por comentar, el archivo es el JS que esta arriba, error mio al decir ajax, y si esta en la home

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido de tu archivo `home.php` exactamente? El mensaje de error dice que intentas acceder a algo que es nulo en la línea `27` de ese archivo. ¿Será acaso este elemento que es nulo `var select_viajes = document.getElementById('viajes');`? ¿Tienes algo declarado con `id="viajes"` en tu HTML. Muestra un ejemplo mínimo y verificable que comprenda todos los elementos, explicando claramente qué es cada cosa.